# HTML Form stops working when I add another form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php function echo out a form if specific parameters are met and everything was working perfectly. After I added the a few more forms under the original form (the php code is almost identical if it matters and the action parameter goes to the same file for them all) the forms above the most recently added form stops working. It continues to show up but the action param does not do anything. I have not seen anything like this before and have no idea how to handle it.

First From and if statements

```
<?php
  $res1 = $_GET['g1'];

  if ($res1 === 'true') {

    $sql = "SELECT gameNumber FROM mainBets WHERE userNumber=?";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($sportsbetsconn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=sql_error");
        exit();
      }
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['userid']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    if(in_array("1",$row) ){
      echo "Bet Placed";

    }else{

      $coins = $_SESSION['coins'];

      echo '<form action="includes/placebet.inc.php" method="post">
      <select name="chosenTeam">

          <option value="TEAM1">TEAM11</option>
          <option value="TEAM2">TEAM2</option>
        </select>
        <input name ="bet-amount" type="number" min="0" max="'.$coins.'">
        <input name ="gameNum" type="hidden" value="1">
        <button type="submit" name="bet-submit">Place Bet</button>';
    }
  }
   ?>
```

Second Form and if statements

```
<?php

  $res2 = $_GET['g2'];
  if ($res2 === 'true'){
    $sql = "SELECT gameNumber FROM mainBets WHERE userNumber=?";
    //$stmt = $sportsbetsconn->query($sql);
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($sportsbetsconn);

    //  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=sql_error");
        exit();
      }
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['userid']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    if(in_array("2",$row) ){
      echo "Bet Placed";



    }else{

      $coins = $_SESSION['coins'];

      echo '<form action="includes/placebet.inc.php" method="post">
      <select name="chosenTeam">

          <option value="TEAM1">TEAM11</option>
          <option value="TEAM2">TEAM2</option>
        </select>
        <input name ="bet-amount" type="number" min="0" max="'.$coins.'">
        <input name ="gameNum" type="hidden" value="2">
        <button type="submit" name="bet-submit">Place Bet</button>';

    }

  }





   ?>
```

Edit
Thank you to everyone that caught the missing `</form>` tag that solves the main problem.

Comment: Could you please update your question to include your code?

Comment: Can u added a example? Or share code in here. Thankyou

Comment: I notice that you are never *closing* your forms (`</form>`). I'm not sure if that would confuse a browser or not.

Comment: I solved it through object oriented programming. Someone told me to make turn it into classes as to save space on the file and the error was fixed. Thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there your code is missing a closing form tag.

Please try updating your echo to this:

```
  echo '<form action="includes/placebet.inc.php" method="post">
  <select name="chosenTeam">

      <option value="TEAM1">TEAM11</option>
      <option value="TEAM2">TEAM2</option>
    </select>
    <input name ="bet-amount" type="number" min="0" max="'.$coins.'">
    <input name ="gameNum" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button type="submit" name="bet-submit">Place Bet</button>
    </form>';
```

Also adjust the second file accordingly.